# How to debug chain stalls?

Tags: stalled, debugging

[image]
As you can see in the image, our chain randomly stalled just short of jumping into the next epoch. I have no clue why. How should I go about debugging such issues?

Comment: What kind of messages do you see in your node cli output?

Comment: Just the regular `Idle` messages. I've restarted the node and now my chain is >4800 blocks w/ the exact chainspec so my guess it is probably to do something with my server experiencing downtime. If I could figure out if my server indeed went down then I can dismiss any problems with the node code/operation and close this question.

Comment: How about right when the blockchain stalls. Certainly there will be some error message which appears.